# how to add cookies to tornado httpclient

Tags: python, tornado

Here is my code

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.fetch("http://www.example.com",
                          callback=self.on_fetch)

    def on_fetch(self, response):
        self.write('hello')
        self.finish()
```

I want to use asynchronous HTTP client. When I fetch the request, I want to send it with the cookies.
The Document has nothing about httpclient cookies. http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpclient.html

Comment: I guess tornado disconnects from browser when `get` function ends. Did you check in browser network console if tornado sends some empty response?

Answer (score 6):

You can put the cookie in the `headers` keyword argument that `fetch` takes.

client:

```
import tornado.httpclient

http_client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()
cookie = {"Cookie" : 'my_cookie=heyhey'}
http_client.fetch("http://localhost:8888/cook",
                  headers=cookie)
```

server:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import tornado.web

class CookHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        cookie = self.get_cookie("my_cookie")
        print "got cookie %s" % (cookie,)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/cook", CookHandler),
    ])

    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

If you run the server, followed by the client, the server will output this:

```
got cookie heyhey
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tornado-httpclient-session
Is a library just for that:

```
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient

from httpclient_session import Session

s = Session(HTTPClient) # AsyncHTTPClient default

r = s.fetch('https://github.com')
print(r.headers['set-cookie']) # Inspect cookies returnd from Github

r = s.fetch('https://github.com') # Fetching carrys cookies
print(r.request.headers['cookie']) # Inspect cookies attached
```

Comment: Author removed the repo and the PyPi page, but I still have [a fork](https://github.com/saaj/tornado-httpclient-session) if someone needs it.